# what is the mean of flutter_background_service_platform_interface

Tags: android, flutter, dart

what is the mean of flutter_background_service_platform_interface?  how i work with this package?what is the benefit of this package?please give me description with code of this package.what is the work of flutter_background_service_platform_interface..Please help me.i am new in flutter.Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's used by flutter_background_service.  Normally you won't talk to it directly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a background service that generally runs in the background of app, you can run this service continuously based on your needs, and perform operations inside this service. This service example available in official in PubDev.

Note:- While running any background service in app, please take permission to user as per GDPR guideline, otherwise app will not accepted